# VS 2010 installation on Win7 x64 breaks

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010

Clean Windows 7 x64 system. Try to install VS 2010 Ultimate and the installation breaks with error:

CRootComponent::Install(): Cannot install; setup files failed verification.

What could be the problem on a clean Win7???

Comment: How much RAM is available in your box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me like botched download/disk.

Comment: hmmmm this is MSDN version. if I don't get a better answer, I'll download it again over the night.

Comment: I downloaded another Professional version and it works. thanks!